# nginx url rewrite (No redirection )

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting

Hi I want to make a nginx rewrite as fllowing

http://my-domain/Canada

to

http://my-domain/rates/callrates.php?c=Canada

user will see the url as http://my-domain/Canada
and the php will execute the page in the following url

http://my-domain/rates/callrates.php?c=Canada

how to enable this in nginx.conf ?

```
server 
{
    listen 80;
    server_name  my-domain.com;
    access_log /home/www/my-domain/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/www/my-domain/logs/error.log;
    root /home/www/my-domain/public_html;
    location / {
        index index.php login.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php?$query_string @extensionless-php;
    error_page  404  /404.php;      
    }
location ~* ^/(?<country>\w+)$ {
    rewrite ^ /testring/callrates.php?c=$country last;
}
 location ~ \.html$ 
 {
    if (!-f $request_filename) 
    {
        rewrite ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php last;
    }
}
location ~ .*\.php$  
    {   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/www/r2wconnect.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
location @extensionless-php 
{
   rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
}
```

Comment: I can't see how the new location block breaks `.css` and `.js` unless their URLs do not have an extension and therefore look like a country name URL.

Comment: Hi i managed to fix it. this is due to base url in html header. now all working perfect. thank you so much for the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you already have a working PHP configuration...

If your domain does nothing else, the default action could be to invoke the script with:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /rates/callrates.php?c=$uri;
}
```

The above has the side effect of leaving in the leading `/`.

If you want to make the rule more specific, you could protect it with a regular expression (which also extracts the country name correctly):

```
location ~* ^/(?<country>\w+)$ {
    rewrite ^ /rates/callrates.php?q=$country last;
}
```

Comment: Hi i treid so but it is giving 404 error for css, js files

Comment: If you edit your question and add your existing `server` block, we can provide advice on integrating the above into it.